# Flexbox elements with column wrapping overlap each other

Tags: css, flexbox

Consider the following nested flex containers, with the parent being row based and the children column based. The two `.container` elements overlap each other which should not happen in a flex layout.

Expected:
[image]

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.container {
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">item1</div>
    <div class="item">item2</div>
    <div class="item">item3</div>
    <div class="item">item4</div>
    <div class="item">item5</div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">itema</div>
    <div class="item">itemb</div>
    <div class="item">itemc</div>
    <div class="item">itemd</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

I expected with flex the elements should nicely line up along side each other, but this does not happen.

If I do `column nowrap` instead on `.container`, then the two elements line up nicely. Interestingly, with `column wrap`, the width of `.container` appears to be one column wide only despite the elements wrapping over into two columns. Maybe this is the root cause? Is the width calculation somehow messed up with wrapping?

If I set `flex-grow` on `.container`, I can get them to not overlap. But then they spread out taking the full width of the parent leaving lots of space in between. `flex-shrink` does not help here.

In the end, I'd like each `.container` element to only take the width it needs, and I'd like to line up all the `.container`s along side each other in a row based layout. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try `flex:1 1 auto`; to your `.container`

Comment: Can you provide an image of how do you want the end result to look like please.

Comment: I have added the expected image.
@Sfili_81 as mentioned, I have tried flex-grow but the elements expand to fill the entire width of the screen. I expect shrink wouldn't help here and auto is the default flex-basis. Would also appreciate if you can explain why a particular solution should work, thanks!